# How to convert a custom observable matrix to a Cirq observable for simulation?

Tags: programming, cirq

I aim to conduct a Cirq simulation using a custom observable. However, the **measure_observables** function in Cirq requires an Iterable of **cirq.PauliString**, making it challenging to directly use a custom observable matrix. Since the observable matrix may vary, hard-coding it with gates becomes impractical. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve

```py
import cirq
import numpy as np
from cirq.work.observable_measurement import measure_observables, RepetitionsStoppingCriteria

# Custom observable matrix
obs_matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0.63, 0.5, 1, 1],
        [0.5, 0.82, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0.33],
        [1, 1, 0.33, 0.3],
    ],
    dtype=float,
)

# Create a Cirq circuit
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
qubits = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)
circuit.append(cirq.H(0))
circuit.append(cirq.rx(1.76)(1))
circuit.append(cirq.measure(qubits, key='result'))

# Run the simulation with custom observable
simulator = cirq.Simulator()
results = measure_observables(
    circuit,
    obs_matrix,
    simulator,
    stopping_criteria=RepetitionsStoppingCriteria(100)
)
print(results)
```

Can anyone advise me how to tackle the matrix hard-coding?

Comment: maybe you could just get the `final_state_vector` from the state vector simulator and compute $\langle \psi | A |\psi\rangle$ with numpy?